# How to get focus on firefox driver in conjunction with TestNG implementing ITestListener

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'd appreciate and thank for any advice here. I am trying to user the driver object from POM framework by use of TestNG and  implementing ITestListerner interface.

This is a TestNG class implementing ItestListener

```
public class TestNGListener implements ITestListener {

@Override
public void onFinish(ITestContext result) {


    WebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.LanuchBrowser("firefox", "http://10.207.182.108:81/opencart/");
    Util.takescreenshot(driver, result.getName());


}
```

This class is used to return a WebDriver Object after launch one of the browser from switch case. I am using same driver as apart of TestNG by implementing Itestlistener & overriding **failure public void onFinish(ITestContext result)** in the above class & unfortunately, it doesn't return a webdriver object & take a screen shot but launches a new browser instead.

```
public class BrowserFactory {

static WebDriver driver;

    public  static WebDriver LanuchBrowser(String Brwsr, String URL){

        System.out.println(Brwsr.toLowerCase());
        switch (Brwsr.toLowerCase()){

            case "firefox":
                        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
                        break;
            case "chrome":
                        driver= new ChromeDriver();
                        System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
                        break;

            case "internet explorer":
                        System.out.println("IE");
                        driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
                        System.setProperty("WebDriver.IE.driver","IEDriverServer.exe");
                        break;
            default:
                        System.out.println("Please select one of the Browsers listed : Chrome,Firefox or InternetExplorer");
                        break;
        }   


            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(URL);                    


        return driver;

    }
}
```

Here is my method to capture screenshot

```
public class Util {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Util.class);      

public static void validatePgeNavgtn(WebDriver driver, String PgeTitle){
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");


    String pgtitle=driver.getTitle();

    if (pgtitle.equalsIgnoreCase(PgeTitle)){
    logger.info("title matched");       
    } 
}

public static void takescreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screen){
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File src=  ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("./Screenshot/"+screen+".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest an approach that below method shouldn't launch a new browser session but the focus should be retained on first browser instance & also capture a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create `BrowserFactory` class as singleton which will create always give single instance of `BrowserFactory` as below :-

```
public class BrowserFactory {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private static BrowserFactory browserFactoryInstance = null;

    private BrowserFactory(String Brwsr, String URL) {

        System.out.println(Brwsr.toLowerCase());
        switch (Brwsr.toLowerCase()) {

        case "firefox":
            this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case "chrome":
            System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;

        case "internet explorer":
            System.out.println("IE");
            System.setProperty("WebDriver.IE.driver", "IEDriverServer.exe");
            this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            break;
        default:
            System.out
                    .println("Please select one of the Browsers listed : Chrome,Firefox or InternetExplorer");
            break;
        }

        this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        this.driver.get(URL);

    }

    public static BrowserFactory getInstance(String Brwsr, String URL) {
        if(browserFactoryInstance == null) {
            browserFactoryInstance = new BrowserFactory(Brwsr, URL);
        }
        return browserFactoryInstance;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return this.driver;
    }
}
```

Now you can get `WebDriver` instance as below :-

```
//It will return always single instance per test run
WebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.getInstance("firefox", "http://10.207.182.108:81/opencart/").getDriver();
Util.takescreenshot(driver, result.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Do I need to included a constructor with an argument as below to be able to use  `browserFactoryInstance = new BrowserFactory(Brwsr, URL);` or should I make a call to `BrowserFactory(String Brwsr, String URL)` from `getInstance()` method.

Comment: @nandeshkalyankar you can't call constructor directly because it's private..you need to call getInstance() instead..